# Verificar o maior número primo - usando somente while e if

Tags: python

Estou com dificuldades em resolver um exercício de lógica, creio que estou pensando de forma errada:

O que preciso: Dado um número N mostrar o maior número primo até N.

O código que fiz até o momento é este:

```
def maior_primo(n):
    print(ePrimo(n))


def ePrimo(k):
    aux = k
    i = 1
    divisores = 0
    while(aux >= 1):
        while(i <= aux):
            if(aux % i == 0):
                divisores += 1
                i += 1
            else:
                i += 1
        if(divisores < 3):
            return aux
        else:
            aux -= 1
```

Porém quando executo me retorna:

```
maior_primo(7)
7

maior_primo(8)
None
```

Fiz os dois `while`s porque 1 está verificando o número que informei e reduzindo ex: `maior_primo(8)`, irá testar o 8 ver que tem mais que dois divisores então irá pegar o número que passei e subtrair 1.

E o outro `while` irá verificar para cada número que for diminuindo quantos divisores ele possuí.

> Observação: Só posso usar duas funções, `while` e `if`.

Comment: Você quer mostrar o maior ou o menor? Se for o menor é fácil, `print(2)`.

Comment: Entendi o que disse, pensei errado quando escrevi é o maior número mesmo

Comment: Só falta um `while` decrementa do `n` até achar um primo chamando `ehPrimo`. Também poderia usar o crivo para pré-povoar os primos

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado, então está no código este `while`

Comment: Não no `ehPrimo`, mas chamando (presente contínuo/gerúndio) `ehPrimo`. Ou seja, dentro de `maior_primo`. E a chamada de `maior_primo` fora do `print`

Comment: A sua função `ePrimo` não está verificando se um número é primo ou não, está tentando resolver o problema do `maior_primo`. Ao invés disso, faça ela retornar `True` se um número é primo e `False` em caso contrário. Tendo ela funcionando, aí sim você vai fazer a `maior_primo`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A sua função `ePrimo` não está verificando se um número é primo ou não, está tentando resolver o problema do `maior_primo`. Ao invés disso, faça ela retornar `True` se um número é primo e `False` em caso contrário. Tendo ela funcionando, aí sim você vai fazer a `maior_primo`.

Um outro detalhe a se levar em conta, é que se *k* é um número é composto, então o maior fator que ele pode ter é a sua raiz quadrada. Você não precisa calcular a raiz quadrada diretamente, apenas verificar que para qualquer possível divisor *i*, se *i<sup>2</sup> <= k*.

Eis como fica o código (incluindo testes):

```
def maior_primo(n):
    aux = n
    while aux > 2:
        if eh_primo(aux):
            return aux
        aux -= 1
    return 2

def eh_primo(k):
    i = 2
    while i * i <= k:
        if k % i == 0:
            return False
        i += 1
    return True

print('Maior primo ate 8: ' + str(maior_primo(8)))
print('Maior primo ate 7: ' + str(maior_primo(7)))
print('Maior primo ate 100: ' + str(maior_primo(100)))
print('Maior primo ate 60: ' + str(maior_primo(60)))
print('Maior primo ate 61: ' + str(maior_primo(61)))
print('Maior primo ate 3: ' + str(maior_primo(3)))
print('Maior primo ate 2: ' + str(maior_primo(2)))
print('Maior primo ate 1: ' + str(maior_primo(1)))
print('Maior primo ate 0: ' + str(maior_primo(0)))
```

Eis a saída produzida:

```
Maior primo ate 8: 7
Maior primo ate 7: 7
Maior primo ate 100: 97
Maior primo ate 60: 59
Maior primo ate 61: 61
Maior primo ate 3: 3
Maior primo ate 2: 2
Maior primo ate 1: 2
Maior primo ate 0: 2
```

[**Veja aqui funcionando no ideone.**](https://ideone.com/n8dD4j)

Comment: Obrigado pela explicação e exemplo, parabéns! :)